# How do <scripts> load inside of comment tags?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, script-tag

The following code is in head section of a page:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Shouldn't the comment tags stop this script from being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Conditional Comments

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Only works with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

IE is *smart* with these style comments (IE conditional comments) and knows to treat them as normal HTML.